Please tell new users where to post questions!
Frequently, new users will post questions as an answer.
For example:

New users don't mean any harm - they just don't know that we want questions to be posted as their own separate question.
When you see this, do two things:

Flag as not an answer.
Leave a comment explaining what the user should do differently. Here's an example:

Hi $NewUser! Please use "Ask Question" to post questions, instead of posting an answer. This ensures that your question is shown on the front page, and keeps discussion focused.

But you can write anything, as long as it follows the rules Be Nice and Assume Good Faith.


A handy userscript for these kind of comments is AutoReviewComments. This will save you a lot of typing.
